# Deploy Roslyn Analyzer NuGet Package with Jenkins and Gradle

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I have built a little C# Code Analyzer with works when used locally as an extension. It is based on the "CodeFix + Analyzer" template from Visual Studio.
However when I want deploy it as a NuGet package and try to install that package it fails saying that there is no `analyzer` folder. This is the error message (german):

```
Es wird versucht, Informationen zu Abhängigkeiten für das Paket "PersStyleCop.1.0.0-b0000029580" bezüglich des Projekts "ConsoleApplication1" mit dem Ziel ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" zu erfassen.
Es wird versucht, Abhängigkeiten für das Paket "PersStyleCop.1.0.0-b0000029580" mit dem DependencyBehavior "Lowest" aufzulösen.
Aktionen zum Installieren des Pakets "PersStyleCop.1.0.0-b0000029580" werden aufgelöst.
Aktionen zum Installieren des Pakets "PersStyleCop.1.0.0-b0000029580" wurden aufgelöst.
Das Paket "PersStyleCop.1.0.0-b0000029580" wird dem Ordner "C:\Users\JannerG\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\packages" hinzugefügt.
Das Paket "PersStyleCop.1.0.0-b0000029580" wurde dem Ordner "C:\Users\JannerG\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\packages" hinzugefügt.
Das Paket "PersStyleCop.1.0.0-b0000029580" wurde "packages.config" hinzugefügt.
Die Skriptdatei "C:\Users\JannerG\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\packages\PersStyleCop.1.0.0-b0000029580\tools\install.ps1" wird ausgeführt....
Join-Path : Der Pfad "C:\Users\JannerG\Documents\Visual Studio 
2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\packages\PersStyleCop.1.0.0-b0000029580\analyzers" kann nicht gefunden werden, da er 
nicht vorhanden ist.In C:\Users\JannerG\Documents\Visual Studio 
2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\packages\PersStyleCop.1.0.0-b0000029580\tools\install.ps1:12 Zeichen:19
+ $analyzersPaths = Join-Path (Join-Path (Split-Path -Path $toolsPath -Parent) "an ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Janner...29580\analyzers:String) [Join-Path], ItemNotFoundExce 
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand

"PersStyleCop 1.0.0-b0000029580" wurde erfolgreich auf "ConsoleApplication1" installiert.
========== Abgeschlossen ==========
```

There is however a `lib\portable45-net45+win8` folder in which the DLL `PersStyleCop` is which should contain the analyzer.

I tweaked the installation script `Install.ps1` so that the `lib` path is used and that DLL is added as an analyzer reference. However it is not added as an analyzer reference but a normal reference and no code analysis is performed.

The folder structure for the created package is like this:

```
lib
    portable45-net45+win8
        PersStyleCop.dll
tools
    install.ps1
    uninstall.ps1
```

So how do I create correct Roslyn NuGet analyzer packages? The deployment is made using Jenkins and Gradle.

Comment: Can you show the contents of the .nupkg? You need to have your analyzer dll in the `analyzers` folder -- otherwise you get the result you have where it considers it a normal reference

Comment: I updated the question with contenst of the nuget

Comment: I really wonder why no analyzer folder is created.

Comment: Not sure why but you can adapt the file yourself and see if it works like that.

Comment: In order to answer this question I will need to know what your nuspec file looks like,  If you installed the roslyn SDK from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.NETCompilerPlatformSDK) then you should have a nupec file with contents like `<file src="*.dll" target="analyzers\dotnet\cs"/>` which will place the analyzer dll under the analyzers folder in the nuget package and allow things to work.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The problem is that i can't adapt it because it's built by a Jenkins server and deployed via Nexus. So when I try to install it I have no chance to change the package manually before installing it over the package manager.

Comment: @JonathonMarolf I have installed the Roselyn SDK (locally). But in this case the NuGet package is built via Jenkins, how is the behavior there, do I also have to install the Rolsyn SDK somehow on Jenkins? The `<file src="*.dll" target="analyzers\dotnet\cs"/>` tag is present because I used the Visual Studio template to create the analyzer. I only changed the analyser itself but not the nuspec or other build relevant files.

Comment: You should not need to tell jenkins to do anything regarding producing a nuget package,  just building the project should produce a nuget package. How have you configured Jenkins?